# CSS hover image position change

Tags: html, css, hover, position

I'm certain it's something super stupid, but I've been stuck for a while, now... So, I have images on a website, and I'd like them to move slightly on hover.

So I have in the HTML:

```
<a href="someaddress"><img class="thumb" src="somefile"/></a>
```

And in the CSS:

```
img.thumb {
    position:relative;
    top:0px;
    background:#333399;

}

img.thumb:hover {
    position:relative;
    top:5px;    
    background:#00CCCC;

}
```

The backgrounds are there just to see whether something is happening. Actually, the background doesn't change, so the hover is never taken into account. Does anyone have an idea why that could be??

**EDIT**

Thanks a lot, everyone!

I actually solved it by throwing in a:

```
a > img.thumb:hover {
position:relative;
top:2px;
}
```

Which worked. Still not exactly sure why it didn't work just with img.thumb:hover...

Comment: didn you try the "a" tag before the "img" tag in the css..?

Comment: or just remove the position property?

Comment: Works a treat [here on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X9qqu/). Are you sure you are linking your CSS file properly?

Comment: It seems to be working, http://jsfiddle.net/K7ttL/ What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/KTpRE/).

The HTML:

```
<div>
<a href="someaddress"><img class="thumb" src="http://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo4w.png"/></a>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
img.thumb {
    position:relative;
    top:0px;

}

img.thumb:hover {
    position:relative;
    top:5px;    
    background:#00CCCC;

}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Can't see anything different?

Comment: Strange, but a psychological satisfaction and confirmation that there was no thing called an issue that was to be solved. Just satisfied him/her by adding a div and a google image - @ocanal

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work, I have checked it here: http://cssdesk.com/XcV2D

Some other styles should be impacting...