# How to change the image on mouse hover immediately using css

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi i am having black and white images on my website on mouse hover need to change the image immediately.But it is taking time to change the image for the first time later on it is changing the images immediately.

Code:

```
 <div id="content">
    <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>theme/images/expertise/1.png" class="images1" onmouseover="this.src='<?php echo base_url();?>theme/images/1.png'" onmouseout="this.src='<?php echo base_url();?>theme/images/expertise/1.png'" />
    <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>theme/images/expertise/2.png" class="images2" onmouseover="this.src='<?php echo base_url();?>theme/images/2.png'" onmouseout="this.src='<?php echo base_url();?>theme/images/expertise/2.png'"/>
</div>
```

Css

```
#content {
  margin-top: 21px;
  margin-bottom: 57px;
 }
.images1,.images2 {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition-property: transform;
    transition-property: transform;
 }
 .images1:hover,
 .images1:focus,
 .images1:active,
 .images2:hover,
 .images2:focus,
 .images2:active
  {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
     transform: scale(1.1);
   }
```

Comment: Whats the question? This is a statement

Comment: What's the image size? Is it too heavy to load and thats why taking lot of time?

Comment: You need to prefetch the hover image. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646036/javascript-preloading-images

Comment: You need to preload images before hover effect if you want to avoid waiting.

Comment: Image size is 137*74

Comment: @ハセン there is no solutions in the link which you shared

Comment: Yes there is. You call this function in javascript and pass it the url of your hover images so they are preloaded.

Comment: Any other suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added the preloader script in header.php file it worked

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function preload(arrayOfImages) {
var ImageContainer ="<div style='display:none;'>";
$(arrayOfImages).each(function(){
 ImageContainer += "<img src='"+this+"''>";
});

ImageContainer +="</div>";
$(".ourexpertise").append(ImageContainer);

}
// Usage:
var arrayOfImages =[
'http://www.example.com/theme/images/1.png',
'http://www.example.com/theme/images/2.png',
'http://www.example.com/theme/images/3.png'
 ];
 $(document).ready(function(){
preload(arrayOfImages);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to create an image holding both pictures in one file.
then you use a div with the desired size and the image as background.

you define the position so, that the first picture is visible and the other not.

if you hover, you change the position, so the other picture gets shown.

Here is a relatively similar question: [CSS hover image position change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16415786/css-hover-image-position-change)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to adjust the URL's, but let me know if this works for you.

```css
.images1,.images2 {
    display: block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    transition: transform .3s ease;
    will-change: transform;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
 }
 .images1:hover,
 .images1:focus,
 .images1:active,
 .images2:hover,
 .images2:focus,
 .images2:active
  {
     transform: scale(1.1);
  }
```

```html
<div id="content">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x100/ffffff" class="images1" onmouseover="this.src='http://placehold.it/350x100/003500'" onmouseout="this.src='http://placehold.it/350x100/ffffff'" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x100/ffffff" class="images2" onmouseover="this.src='http://placehold.it/350x100/003500'" onmouseout="this.src='http://placehold.it/350x100/ffffff'"/>
</div>
```

Comment: No it is displaying the same only as previous